# Initialize contents of Coldfusion tab on page load.

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Using Coldfusion 9, I have a cflayout tab control with two tabs.  The first tab loads when the page loads by default, which is fine.  I would also like the contents inside the second tab to be initialized on page load instead of loading when the user clicks the tab, but I don't want to actually select the second tab.  I want the first tab to be remain the default(selected) tab.

Comment: Not sure how to initialize the tab, however, my workaround was to set the second tab to selected in the cflayout (selected="true") and used document.onload to execute ColdFusion.Layout.selectTab('mytabcontrol','mytabname') which immediately set the tab back to the first tab.  This appears to be completely transparent to the user.  Still open to ideas for a better solution.

Comment: Do yourself a favor...stop using `cflayout`,  or any other of the client side ColdFusion functionality - they are poorly implemented, out dated and woefully limited in functionality.